# Fetching MongoDB Records with Non-Empty Image Fields using Laravel-MongoDB

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

Hello wonderful community of developers,

I am working on a project that involves querying my MongoDB database using Laravel, specifically with the laravel-mongodb package. Within this database, I have a collection of advertisements, some of which include an "images" field. This "images" field stores an array of images associated with each advertisement.

My challenge lies in creating a query that retrieves only those advertisements that satisfy two key criteria:

They have the "images" field present.
The "images" field contains actual image values, while excluding records where the "images" field is an empty array.

In pursuit of this, I have formulated the following code snippet:

```
$advertisements = Advertisement::query()->where('status', Advertisement::ACTIVE);
$advertisements->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('images', 'exists', true)
          ->whereRaw([
              '$expr' => [
                  '$gt' => [
                      ['$size' => '$images'],
                      0
                  ]
              ]
          ]);
});
```

While the above query seems promising, I have not been able to achieve the desired outcome. It appears that the $expr condition I'm using does not function as intended when interacting with the laravel-mongodb package.

If any of you kind souls have experience with the intricacies of the laravel-mongodb package and can guide me toward constructing an effective query for excluding advertisements with empty image arrays, your insights would be of immense help. Your expertise will play a crucial role in advancing my project.

I wholeheartedly appreciate your time and consideration in reading this query. Thank you in advance for sharing your knowledge, and I eagerly await your valuable suggestions and recommendations.